# Failed to connect to cloudsql server when following Google App Engine tutorial (Python + Flask)

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I followed the tutorial for Google App Engine (GAE) for a bookshelf app at https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app

While I have revised the config.py and app.yaml as per instruction to connect to database, when I then executed the code "python bookshelf/model_cloudsql.py", the below error message showed up:

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

I guess this error means that my cloudSQL server was not listened to the request, but I tried to connect to my cloudSQL server via cloud shell, it worked well with username root and corresponding password.

Could anyone help to figure out what the problem is?

Thanks a lot!

Code for Config.py is:

```
import os

# The secret key is used by Flask to encrypt session cookies.
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# There are three different ways to store the data in the application.
# You can choose 'datastore', 'cloudsql', or 'mongodb'. Be sure to
# configure the respective settings for the one you choose below.
# You do not have to configure the other data backends. If unsure, choose
# 'datastore' as it does not require any additional configuration.
DATA_BACKEND = 'cloudsql'

# Google Cloud Project ID. This can be found on the 'Overview' page at
# https://console.developers.google.com
PROJECT_ID = 'changpei-175109'

# CloudSQL & SQLAlchemy configuration
# Replace the following values the respective values of your Cloud SQL
# instance.
CLOUDSQL_USER = 'root'
CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXX'
CLOUDSQL_DATABASE = 'novel'
# Set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name, e.g.
#   "project:region:cloudsql-instance".
# You must also update the value in app.yaml.
CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME = 'changpei-175109:asia-northeast1:novel'

# The CloudSQL proxy is used locally to connect to the cloudsql instance.
# To start the proxy, use:
#
#   $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=your-connection-name=tcp:3306
#
# Port 3306 is the standard MySQL port. If you need to use a different port,
# change the 3306 to a different port number.

# Alternatively, you could use a local MySQL instance for testing.
LOCAL_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@127.0.0.1:3306/{database}').format(
        user=CLOUDSQL_USER, password=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=CLOUDSQL_DATABASE)

# When running on App Engine a unix socket is used to connect to the cloudsql
# instance.
LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{database}'
    '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{connection_name}').format(
        user=CLOUDSQL_USER, password=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=CLOUDSQL_DATABASE, connection_name=CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME)

if os.environ.get('GAE_INSTANCE'):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
else:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = LOCAL_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI

# Mongo configuration
# If using mongolab, the connection URI is available from the mongolab control
# panel. If self-hosting on compute engine, replace the values below.
MONGO_URI = \
    'mongodb://user:password@host:27017/database'
```

app.yaml is:

```
    runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

#[START cloudsql_settings]
beta_settings:
    # If using Cloud SQL, uncomment and set this value to the Cloud SQL
    # connection name, e.g.
    #   "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    # You must also update the values in config.py.
    # 
  cloud_sql_instances: "changpei-175109:asia-northeast1:novel"
#[END cloudsql_settings]
```

And for model_cloudsql.py is:

```
 from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


builtin_list = list


db = SQLAlchemy()


def init_app(app):
    # Disable track modifications, as it unnecessarily uses memory.
    app.config.setdefault('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS', False)
    db.init_app(app)


def from_sql(row):
    """Translates a SQLAlchemy model instance into a dictionary"""
    data = row.__dict__.copy()
    data['id'] = row.id
    data.pop('_sa_instance_state')
    return data


# [START model]
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    author = db.Column(db.String(255))
    publishedDate = db.Column(db.String(255))
    imageUrl = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    createdBy = db.Column(db.String(255))
    createdById = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Book(title='%s', author=%s)" % (self.title, self.author)
# [END model]


# [START list]
def list(limit=10, cursor=None):
    cursor = int(cursor) if cursor else 0
    query = (Book.query
             .order_by(Book.title)
             .limit(limit)
             .offset(cursor))
    books = builtin_list(map(from_sql, query.all()))
    next_page = cursor + limit if len(books) == limit else None
    return (books, next_page)
# [END list]


# [START read]
def read(id):
    result = Book.query.get(id)
    if not result:
        return None
    return from_sql(result)
# [END read]


# [START create]
def create(data):
    book = Book(**data)
    db.session.add(book)
    db.session.commit()
    return from_sql(book)
# [END create]


# [START update]
def update(data, id):
    book = Book.query.get(id)
    for k, v in data.items():
        setattr(book, k, v)
    db.session.commit()
    return from_sql(book)
# [END update]


def delete(id):
    Book.query.filter_by(id=id).delete()
    db.session.commit()


def _create_database():
    """
    If this script is run directly, create all the tables necessary to run the
    application.
    """
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile('../config.py')
    init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    print("All tables created")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _create_database()
```

Comment: Can you please share your `config.py` and `app.yml` which you say have modified? The possible issue might be because of the ports or the IP mismatching.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817479/python-pymysql-err-operationalerror-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-dur. I hope this will help you. Also for information: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/7571/

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I've posted the code as in the original question. Will look into the links you provided